# Joomla 3.1 setup on Ubuntu 12.04 running nginx

Tags: joomla, nginx, permissions, ubuntu-12.04

My objective is to have Joomla 3.1 running on an Ubuntu server using nginx.

I am testing the setup locally but I keep encountering problems. I think this is concerned with the permissions in my Joomla source files.

I tried to install a package (T3) manually using the "Install From Directory" option. However, I receive the following message:

> Warning JFTP: :store: Bad response
>
> JInstaller: :Install: Failed to copy file
>   /usr/share/nginx/immigrationinformation.com/components/com_installer/t3-1.4.1/source/plg_system_t3/t3.php
>   to
>   /usr/share/nginx/immigrationinformation.com/plugins/system/t3/t3.php
>
> Package Install: There was an error installing an extension:
>   plg_system_t3

I know that this is the wrong way to set up the server but currently I have all the source files permissions set to 777. When this T3 package tries to install, it creates a folder in `plugins/system/` called `t3`. This has only permissions `drwxr-xr-x` and thus the reason for the above errors.

My question is: What is the correct method to set up my Joomla 3.1 package such that I can ensure a smooth operation of the site, in a secure manner.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The permissions when t3 installs are correct, it sounds like the problem is with ownership rather than permissions.

I think in ubuntu the system user is www-data so you would need to run the following over ssh

```
chown -hR www-data:www-data /path/to/joomla/root
```

Then upload the plugin through the joomla installer (and change folder permissions back to 755 and files to 644).